# Does the illumination color (red/blue/green) has any effect over the disparity map generated from a stereo image?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a working model that creates a disparity map using stereoscopic image processing using opencv. I am thinking of improving the disparity map by using illumination and stuck with different options in the light colors. I want to know if the color of illumination has any influence over the disparity maps.